# What classes in the .NET Platform use the Singleton design pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, singleton

**What classes in the .NET Platform use the *Singleton* pattern?**

Just want to take a look at them through Reflector and see how are implemented, and more than it, how Singleton can be used in different contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`System.DBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx):

```
public sealed class DBNull 
{
   public static readonly DBNull Value;

   static DBNull()
   {
      Value = new DBNull();
   }

   private DBNull() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much where you see `Provider` in the name. Especially in the FormsAuthenication and Membership parts of ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the `Settings` classes which derive from `System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase`. Pretty much all the application/user scope settings are managed by singleton instances.